# Merge multiple JSON files outputs in one list object

Tags: python, json, list

I have a folder that contains many JSON files. I want to write Python code that scans all files, reads them, and merges them into a single list object.

I tried the following.

```py
mypath = 'C:/Users/data'
files = ['f1.josn', 'f2.josn', ..., 'f20.josn']
output_list = []
for file in files:
    with open(mypath+'/'+file, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        output_list.append(json.load(infile))
```

I got a traceback after running the above code:

```py
JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1002 column 99 (char 38611)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in one (or all) of the json-files. Quoting [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) page:

> If the data being deserialized is not a valid JSON document, a JSONDecodeError will be raised.